# Declaring a delegating method as constexpr whenever the invoked function is specified with constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, c++17

Please consider the following class

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
public:
    auto bar() { return m_t.bar(); }

private:
    T m_t;
};
```

If we want `foo<T>::bar` to be non-throwing whenever `T::bar` is non-throwing, we can change its declaration to

```
auto bar() noexcept(noexcept(m_t.bar())) { return m_t.bar(); }
```

But what can we do, if we want `foo<T>::bar` to be specified with `constexpr` whenever `T::bar` is specified with `constexpr`?

Can we just write

```
constexpr auto bar() noexcept(noexcept(m_t.bar())) { return m_t.bar(); }
```

and it will work in either case? I've tested this with clang 3.7 (C++17) and it seems to be the case, but I'm not sure whether or not the compiler is working correctly here.

Comment: Remember that `constexpr` is still just a hint, it may be evaluated compile-time but doesn't have to be. This allows your method signature to work for both cases, so yeah, this is valid.

Answer (score 5):

From [[dcl.constexpr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6):

> If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, that specialization is still a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Given that there are `T`s that could have a `constexpr X bar()` that can be used in a constant expression, the template is fine. If `T` has a non-`constexpr` `bar()`, then `foo::bar` is still considered `constexpr` but just cannot appear in a constant expression.

Comment: you could expand this answer by noting that the default constructor (and perhaps other special members, didn't check) can be implicitly `constexpr` (if all their members are `constexpr`), and then the keyword can be left out. Also, if there is any forbidden construct inside `bar()` (a `goto` or `new` etc.) then the compiler will deduce that no `T` can render `bar` as `constexpr`.

Comment: @TemplateRex That may be just out of scope? I don't want the answer to just list all the rules of `constexpr`. (And yes, the same is true for copy/move construction/assignment as well. )

Comment: Yeah probably out of scope. Although I do wish for something like `constexpr(auto)` :)

Comment: @TemplateRex Need moar auto :)